# How can install pod file in aggregate framework in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode12

I am working on custom framework so I create aggregate framework and also I wan to install cocoapods in project so I can able to install cocoapods but when I archive the project at that time "no module found CocoaMQTT"> I am using below script to archive the project .

Script

####################

## Optional Value

####################
REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=true

####################

## Required Values

####################
FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"
SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"
FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
######################

## Build Frameworks

######################
xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1
xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1
######################

## Create directory for universal

######################
rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"
mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"
mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"
######################

## Copy files Framework

######################
cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"
######################

## Printing Paths for your referance

######################
echo SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH
echo "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
echo DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH
echo "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
echo UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR
echo "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"
######################

## Make an universal binary

######################
lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo
######################

## For Swift framework, Swiftmodule needs to be copied in the universal framework

######################
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
cp -f ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
fi
if [ -d "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
cp -f ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
fi
######################

## On Release, copy the result to release directory

######################
OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/Output/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"
rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"
cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"
if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then
open "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"
fi

Podfile :
[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: use podspec for your framework and add an MQTT as dependence

Answer (score 2):

**The first problem is with your Build Framework, as you have installed pods you have workspace not the project. So build should be done with workspace and scheme**

######################

Build Frameworks

######################

xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1 -UseModernBuildSystem=NO

xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1 -UseModernBuildSystem=NO

######################

Try this, hope this helpful. Also check below answer if you want to distribute xcframework.
[iOS Dyanmic Framework with Firebase Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725471/ios-dyanmic-framework-with-firebase-dependencies)